# MVVM, where to put/handle ui events such as 'onClick'

Tags: mvvm, architecture, mvp

I know this is a vague question, but I was so fixated in MVP design, for years, I decided to keep myself up to date and decided to venture to **MVVM** architecture design, I've been reading alot of blogs, samples and stuffs about the Stream/Observer pattern that **MVVM** follows, but what is not clear with me(cant find very very simple code) how does MVVM handle ui-events? such as onclick? in MVP, the view and the presenter has a two-way contract to handle such thing

```
// called by view
presenter.onViewButtonClicked 



void onViewButtonClicked() {

      // do something here that business logic requires
      view.doSomethingAfterPresenterReceivedClickEvent() 
}
```

I know that View in MVVM **subscribe's** to ViewModel that when something happened to the data(Model) **View** will **react** to it

now, how can I tell ViewModel that I clicked something? *( PS : I know that I have to subscribe to ViewModel to listen to any changes when I clicked something )*, I just need some guidelines and examples how can I tell VM that I did something intentionally.

I read Microsoft's MVVM documentation and it says something about iCommand, a contract-like something to tell MVVM a UI-event occurred.

would anyone enlighten me please... Thanks in advance

Edit: I forgot to mention, Im not using DataBinding, and due to fair pros and cons, I decided not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am truly not an **MVVM** expert, but from my knowledge:

The main difference between **MVP** and **MVVM** is that in **MVP**, there is a two way connection between the *view* and the *presenter*, which means that the *presenter* knows about the *view (interface)* and the *view* knows about the *presenter (interface)*.

In **MVVM** on the other hand, this connection is only one way, which means that the *view* knows about the *viewmodel*, but the *viewmodel* doesn't know about the view (since the connection from the *viewmodel* to the *view* is handled via observed data). 
This allows the *viewmodel* to be independent of any *view* or *view implementation* and allows a single *viewmodel* to be used by multiple *views*.

So to (finally) answer your initial question: the way 'onClick' events are handled is basicly the same in **MVP** and **MVVM** .. the *view* notifies the *presenter* / *viewmodel* about the event and then:

- the *presenter* sets up the data in the model and calls the according methodes on the *view* (in **MVP**)
- the *viewmodel* sets up changed data which automatically triggers a reaction on the *view* since that data is observed (in **MVVM**)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the response, so its almost the same with MVP, i should be able to tell/connect to VM that i did something, but still i have to adhere that even if i detach VM, it will be independent on the View, thank you, but im still hoping that someone will atleast give a link for such an example related...